# Interfacing LIN bus with CAN

Tags: automotive, can, bus, protocol, lin

On the following figure, LIN is used to build subnetworks from a CAN bus:

[image: CAN bus network with LIN subnets]

Is there any standardized way to interface these two buses (e.g. for addressing a LIN node from a CAN node)? I read an [article on Hackaday](https://hackaday.com/2017/05/26/embed-with-elliot-lin-is-for-hackers/) that states that this is the case:

> There is even an optional transport layer spec that is compatible with CAN bus and makes it easier to integrate the local LIN cluster with the bigger network.

However, I cannot any specification related to this. Is this really standardized or is everyone doing it differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [ISO 15765-2](https://www.iso.org/standard/66574.html) and is mentioned in "3.2 Transport Layer" of the [LIN spec](https://www.cs-group.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/LIN_Specification_Package_2.2A.pdf).

Comment: It seems that this was introduced in revision 2.1 while the article links the 2.0 revision.